# ¿Cómo desvanecer un texto 3D en Unity en relación a su rotación?

Tags: unity3d

Me gustaría saber si alguien podría darme un ejemplo sobre cómo hacer un desvanecimiento de textos 3D en relación con la rotación en Unity. Para ser más claro, a medida que se va girando el texto 3d que se vaya desvaneciendo.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Podrías hacer un script que en el update cogiera los valores de rotación del transform del objeto, y en función del valor setearlos a la transparencia del objeto. Hasta ahora que has probado?

Comment: Estoy en eso, aún no lo he logrado. Estoy tratando de hacer el código. Soy novato en lo que es Unity y C#, mucho más en Unity, estoy averiguando cómo lograr hacerlo. Necesitaría un ejemplo para ir aprendiendo. También ando en la búsqueda. Gracias por comentar.

Comment: Bienvenido...ElVigo.., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,  te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado o investigado, más información, etc, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Yo haria un script con lo siguiente:

primero: una propiedad SpriteRenderer;

```
private SpriteRenderer sr;
```

segundo: en el metodo start capturamos el SpriteRenderer del propio objeto. En SpriteRenderer se encuentran varias propiedades, entre ellas el color del objeto. Uno de sus componentes es `a`, que representa el alpha (transparencia):

```
void start() {
  sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}
```

por ultimo, en el metodo update creamos un color y seteamos el parametro alfa, con un valor entre 0 y 1, dependiendo del maximo y minimo del rotation del transform

```
void update() {
  Color color = new Color();
  color.a = .5f; // aqui tienes que poner el valor del rotation que te interese
  sr.Color = color;
}
```

Te dejo la parte de asignar el valor del estado de rotacion. Como pista, te indico que lo puedes obtener del propio transform del objeto, asi:

```
transform.rotation.x
```

puedes cambiar x por las componentes x, y,z y w del quaternio asociado. Averigua tu como transformarlo en un rango 0-1 para asignarlo :)